# "ps" command doesn't return to prompt

Tags: process, ps

I have this busybox/linux box that I need to maintain periodically. To do that, I issue a `ps` command programmatically and check the running processes.

But as shown in the screenshot, sometimes, the `ps` command does not terminate and return to the prompt, it just stays there, and so my application cannot proceed.

It's also obvious that previous `ps` commands are still running while the current one (i.e. which's output is shown in the screenshot) is also hanged.

Does anyone know what could be the problem and how to fix it ?

[image: ps command hanged]

Comment: Have you checked log files? Could you try e.g.: `strace -vf ps aux 2>&1 | tee /tmp/ps.strace`. And take a look at that file.

Comment: Thank you. But that box has a customly built Linux and the commands (`strace` & `aux`) doesn't exist. While the `tee` commands causes the same behavior. I tried copying the `ps.strace` file locally to check it on a windows machine but it only contained the following line:
`-sh: strace: command not found`

Comment: Too bad. (`aux` wasn't important, only a reflex on my part.). Is the system built on some distro as base (the Linux)? What is the version of `ps`? `ps --version` or the like. Does `lsof` give you anything to work with? E.g. `lsof -p <PID_OF_HUNG_PS> | grep proc`. And again; anything in log files? Looks like you have root access, could you install `strace`?

Comment: … and is that two attempts on `reboot` also hanging there (PID `2398` and `2471`)? If it is I guess there is more then `ps` that has trouble. Log-files should hopefully give some indication on what is going on.

Comment: I don't know the distro but `uname -a` outputs:
`Linux HST-R1 2.6.25.4 #1 Mon Oct 26 15:28:50 EDT 2009 ppc unknown`
I also remember we are using `busybox`. `lsof` isn't installed and `ps` doesn't support the `--version` option. I'm sorry I'm not very good with linux. What other logs can I inspect ?
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Do not know `HST`, but that is an fairly old kernel version. You should also get open files of process by `ls -la /proc/<PID_OF_PS>/fd/` – (Only wondering if it is stuck on a specific file). For other information in `/proc/` look at [PROC(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). As for log files look in `/var/log/`. As it is an custom build you have to poke around, but you should have something like `messages`, `dmesg`, `kern.log` etc. Look e.g. here: [Some of the logfiles](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/08/linux-var-log-files/). Do you have `sysctl`? `sysctl fs.file-nr`.

Answer (score 6):

`D` in the fourth column means that the process is currently engaged in a system call. This system state normally lasts for a very short time, so it's unusual to observe it. Observing `D` tends to indicate either a slow I/O (e.g. on a network filesystem) — which `ps` isn't doing — or something wrong in the kernel or with the hardware.

Either you're observing a kernel bug, or some part of your hardware is failing. To know more, the first step is in finding log files. Your system is running [BusyBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BusyBox) and your screenshot shows that it's running `syslogd` with no parameters so all the system logs are in `/var/log/messages`. There's a good chance that this file contains some indication of what's going wrong. If you need help interpreting the logs, edit them into your question (or put them up online somewhere if they're too large).

Comment: Do you know if BusyBox has [`/proc/[pid]/syscall`](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=ebcb67341fee34061430f3367f2e507e52ee051b) or [`ftrace`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt).

Comment: @Sukminder `/proc/$pid/syscall` and ftrace are kernel features, so it doesn't matter that the userland is using BusyBox. They aren't available here because neither exist in kernel 2.6.25. Good idea though, for more recent kernels.

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of suggestions. Let's just not worry about the why it happens but the how to run ps without an issue occurring.

Here are a few suggestions that would be easy to try given your level of experience with linux/unix:

1. Try running `ps auxwwf > myprocesses && cat myprocesses`.
   This will give you a list of all running processes with detailed information and if the first command is successful you will be able to read the contents of myprocesses.
2. Don't use `ps` by itself. There are many different variations but my personal favorite is `auxwwf`. Another good one is `ps lax`.
3. Try sending the process to the background by doing: `ps auxwwf &`
   Then you can type `jobs` and see the PID of the ps process. You can then bring it up by typing `fg`. To send your ps command to the background again you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>.
   This way, you control `ps`. If it hangs you can open another terminal session and kill the PID associated with it.

Let me know if those work for you. They are just a few things you can try as a work around. I'm sure someone will have other ways.

Comment: Thank you, but `ps` available options is `w` for "wide output" only>

Comment: And you can't sudo? does "cat /etc/*release" give you anything?

Comment: This system is running Busybox, not some desktop/server distribution. There is no `ps ax` or `/etc/*release` or `sudo` on such systems. Not that they would help — what are 1 and 2 supposed to work around? Options to `ps` wouldn't make any difference. 3 lets you continue using the shell but that won't affect the stuck processes.

Comment: @Gilles I was just trying to be helpful and offer some advice. I've never heard of busybox. You should be more constructive in your criticism and try to contribute to the conversation in a positive manner.

Comment: Mister - Nothing in Gilles' answer was a criticism as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Today have seen the same kind of issue. the issue is the n/w latency. identified via *ping* command.

```
64 bytes from 172.16.60.143: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=300 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.60.143: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=293 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.60.143: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=258 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.60.143: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=268 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.60.143: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=250 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.60.143: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=282 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.60.143: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=233 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.60.143: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=259 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.60.143: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=288 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.60.143: icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=240 ms
```

NOTE: If you are connecting servers via VPN. try to log in different ISP solve this issue.

Comment: The shown `ps` output indicates that there are other issues with the system than network latency. There are several `ps` processes hanging as well as two `reboot` commands.  This likely does not have to do with network issues.