# htop crashing to blank screen

Tags: proc, crash, htop

I'm trying to run `htop` on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. Until the end of last week the command was working fine, and I haven't made any major changes to the system since then. Now, when I attempt to run `htop`, the screen goes black and I'm unable to exit using `Ctrl-C`, `Ctrl-Z`, `q`, or any of the standard escape characters. I'm forced to restart the terminal.

`top` still works just fine.

EDIT2: I ran

```
strace -o strace.log -f xterm -e htop
```

Examination of the output reveals that the `htop` reads all the existing processes until it gets to the last one, where it does

```
    41049 read(5, "72165 (python) D 1 72113 72069 0"..., 2048) = 190
    41049 read(5, "", 1858)                 = 0
    41049 close(5)                          = 0
    41049 stat("/proc/72113/task/72165", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
    41049 open("/proc/72113/task/72165/cmdline", O_RDONLY) = 5
    41049 read(5,  <unfinished ...>
```

and then it never finishes reading the file.

Running `ps -ef` also causes the terminal to hang. It prints the names of all the processes before `72113`, and then it freezes at `72113` and can't be escaped without closing the terminal.

If I type

```
    sudo less /proc/72113/task/72165/cmdline
```

the terminal hangs. I have also tried

```
    sudo kill -9 72113
```

which runs but does nothing; `htop` and `ps -ef` still freeze when run.

I'm puzzled about what's going on here.

Comment: No, the output stopped in the middle of printing the line. The call was probably just fine. Doesn't explain what happened though.

Comment: Could try `strace -o` to send the output elsewhere, or something like `strace -f xterm -e htop` (though that'll add a lot of xterm noise, thankfully in a different process). Just in case its being cut off due to htop trying to control the terminal.

Comment: What about `hd /proc/72113/task/72165/cmdline` (to see if the problem is reading from the file, or displaying some special character that it contains)? (You should post this output in your question, but check that it doesn't contain any confidential information.) Whch terminal emulator are you using, and can you reproduce this problem with a different one?

Comment: Err, I'd check `dmesg`, not being able to read that file makes me think something is wrong with the kernel. Or the hardware (e.g., bad RAM). Also, how confident are you in the security of the system? If your previous assessment was "unsure" I'd downgrade it to "somewhat worried, investigate": could be a buggy rootkit trying to hide that process.

Comment: I noticed [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81285/how-to-kill-a-process-which-cant-be-killed-without-rebooting) is basically the same problem I'm having. I wonder if a system restart may be necessary.

Comment: What specifically would I look for with `dmesg`? I haven't had much experience with this. And I think the system should be secure, but that's a good suggestion to check.